# Possible bug while defining a vertex attribute

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-attributes

I'm getting a segmentation fault while trying to compile a vertex shader. I think I identified the problem in passing vertex attributes. The following lines compile (they might not work, but they still compile):

```
# version 330
layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Loc;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;
layout(location=2) in vec4 in_Norm;
```

Also

```
# version 330
layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Loc;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;
layout(location=25) in vec4 in_Norm;
```

but

```
# version 330
layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Loc;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;
layout(location=2) in vec4 in_Norm;
layout(location=33) in vec4 in_Anything
```

will not compile. I guess I can only define 3 vec4 attributes. However glGetIntegerv with GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS returns 16 which is in accordance to OpenGL standard. Is this some kind of bug related to my hardware? I'm using a Intel Graphics Card

```
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:49 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

and mesa 10:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile.
```

OS is ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why are you specifying so big location index if your GL only have 16 attributes? But it shouldn't crash anyway, could you add c crash backtrace to your question?

Comment: @keltar: While trying to find the source of the error, I tried "normal" locations and the effect was the same. I'm not sure how to get the c crash backtrace, as I'm getting a simple segmentation fault during glCompileShader.

Comment: Run in debugger (`gdb ./your_program`), then when crash is reported, type `bt` command. It is always good to use debugger.

Comment: @keltar: It will take me a bit of time to do that, because I'm calling the function from python (using cython). But I cannot imagine that that could be the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake thanks to your comment. After creating a test case using only c the glsl file compiled. It turned out that segmentation fault happened in "cython" but not if I called the library directly from c (although there was a "bug" in c). The error was produced by adding an extra line into the glsl file, which triggered the segmentation fault. I was puzzled by that and thought that the error was in compiling the glsl. However, the problem was in the function loading the glsl file:

```
void load_file(const char* fname, char** buffer)
{
    FILE* fp;
    long fsize;
    fprintf(stdout, "Loading %s \n", fname);
    fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", fname);
      exit(1);
    }
    *buffer = (char* ) malloc(fsize + 1);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", (int ) fsize);
    fread(*buffer, fsize, 1, fp);
    buffer[fsize] = 0;
    fclose(fp);
}
```

By replacing buffer[fsize] = 0; with buffer[0][fsize] = 0; I solved the problem. I don't know where does this comes from, nor whether this is actually a bug in my code, but it might be related to how cython allocates memory.